Plotting a route through 2d list using Cartesian coordinates output issue
I'm trying to plot a 'drone' route through a Grid based on 'NSEW' directions from a txt file, as well as outputting the cartesian coordinates of the drone position. When running the code, either the grid is correct and the coordinates are wrong or the coordinates are wrong. I am having to use idiosyncratic fixes such as keeping track of 2 drone_pos variables which feels unnecessary. I suspect its something to do with the indexing:
def file2list(file):
    """
    Helper function that converts a file to a list
    """
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
    
    return lines 

def cart2index(x, y, height):
    idxX = x - 1
    idxY = height - y

    return [idxY, idxX]

def cart2indexreverse(x, y, height):
    idxX = x - 1
    idxY = height - y

    return [idxX, idxY]


def index2cart(x, y, height):
    Xcoord = x + 1
    Ycoord = height - y

    return [Xcoord, Ycoord]
...

    for row in grid:
        print(str(row))

*driver function*

output:
[1, 10]
[2, 10]
[3, 10]
[3, 11]
[4, 11]
[5, 11]
[6, 11]
[6, 10]
[6, 9]
[6, 8]
[7, 8]
[8, 8]
[8, 9]
[8, 10]
[9, 10]
[9, 9]
[9, 8]
[9, 7]
[9, 6]
[8, 6]
[7, 6]
[6, 6]
[5, 6]
[5, 7]
[4, 7]
[3, 7]
[3, 6]
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
[4, 4]
[5, 4]
[5, 3]
[6, 3]
[7, 3]
[7, 4]
[8, 4]
[9, 4]
[10, 4]
[11, 4]
[12, 4]
[12, 3]
[11, 3]
[11, 2]
[11, 1]
[0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, '+', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, '+', '+', 0, 0, '+', '+', '+', 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, '+', 0, 0, 0, '+', 0, '+', '+', 0, 0, 0]
[0, '+', 0, 0, 0, '+', '+', 0, '+', '+', 0, 0]
[0, '+', '+', '+', '+', 0, '+', 0, 0, '+', 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, '+', 0, '+', 0, '+', '+', 0, 0]
[0, 0, '+', '+', '+', 0, '+', 0, '+', 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', 0, '+', 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '+', 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '+', '+', '+', 'x']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '+', '+', 0, 0]

Grid is correct but the coordinates should be:
[3, 12]
[3, 11]
[3, 10]
[2, 10]
[2, 9]
[2, 8]
[2, 7]
[3, 7]
[4, 7]
[5, 7]
[5, 6]
[5, 5]
[4, 5]
[3, 5]
[3, 4]
[4, 4]
[5, 4]
[6, 4]
[7, 4]
[7, 5]
[7, 6]
[7, 7]
[7, 8]
[6, 8]
[6, 9]
[6, 10]
[7, 10]
[8, 10]
[8, 9]
[9, 9]
[9, 8]
[10, 8]
[10, 7]
[10, 6]
[9, 6]
[9, 5]
[9, 4]
[9, 3]
[9, 2]
[9, 1]
[10, 1]
[10, 2]
[11, 2]
[12, 2]




issue is here
def index2cart(x, y, height):
    Xcoord = x + 1
    Ycoord = height - y

    return [Xcoord, Ycoord]

I assume this is supposed to be the inverse of
def cart2index(x, y, height):
    idxX = x - 1
    idxY = height - y

    return [idxY, idxX]

it should be
def index2cart(y, x, height):
    Xcoord = x + 1
    Ycoord = height - y

    return [Xcoord, Ycoord]

notice that I swapped the x,y coords in the args
